# How to express type of "slice of (string or 'other such slice')"

Tags: go, types, abstract-syntax-tree, algebraic-data-types

**How can I express in Go a type which is "a list of (strings or other such lists)"?** Basically the good ol' "tree represented as infinitely nested lists of lists and something as values (strings in this example)"

I'm looking for the simplest possible representation of an S-expression (which itself would be the simplest of an AST), which in Python would look like this:

```
sexp1 = ["+", "x", "y", ["*", "10", "myVal"]]
sexp2 = ["foo" "bar" "baz"]
sexp3 = [ [ [["gooo"], "moo"] ], "too", ["yoo", "2"] ]
```

What type would all these expressions have in Go? Obviously `[][]string` doesn't work, as this doesn't work:

```
func makeSexp(parserName string, values ...[][]string) [][]string {
    return append([]string{parserName}, values...)
}
```

(Compile errors: 1. `cannot use values (type [][][]string) as type []string in append`, 2. `cannot use append([]string literal, values...) (type []string) as type [][]string in return argument`.)

...while the fully untyped version works (**but I don't want to completely give up type safety!**):

```
func makeSexp(parserName string, values ...interface{}) interface{} {
    return append([]interface{}{parserName}, values...)
}
```

Comment: Create a `ListHolder` and `StringHolder` type. Define an interface with two methods: `What_type_are_you` and `Give_me_your_value`.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, Go doesn't support algebraic data types, so your best bet to make it type-safe is to create an unexported interface, and make two implementations of it:

```
type sExp interface {
    sExp()
}

type s string

func (s) sExp() {}

type l []sExp

func (l) sExp() {}

// ...
var sexp1 sExp = l{s("+"), s("1"), s("2"), l{s("*"), s("10"), s("myVal")}}
```

This is basically how Protobuf compilers deal with e.g. `oneof` cases. This will still need a lot of type switches or type assertions to work with, but at least you can be sure that nothing outside of your module will be able to tinker with it.

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/KOvFqJEvxZ.

Comment: two questions about this though: *(1)* why would `sExp()` empty method be even needed, since it looks like this is basically equivalent to aliasing `interface{}` to `sExp` and *(2)* why doesn't a function with type like `func makeSexp(parserName string, values ...sExp) sExp` satisfy a type defined as `type ASTreeMaker func(parserName string, values ...interface{}) interface{}`, even if we just do a `type sExp interface{}` so they should now clearly be the same ...I'm more and more confused :)

Comment: @NeuronQ The method is there as a marker. So that nobody outside your module could create a type that satisfies `sExp` interface. And you cannot assign `[]sExp` to `[]interface{}` because those types are not [assignable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability). There is even an [FAQ entry](https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_with_same_underlying_type) about this.

Comment: uhm, ok, *"you can't change the name (and method set) of elements of a composite type"* is an eye opener, thx for pointing to that ...but I'll probably work with `interface{]` until I get to a working design, then see if there's a safer way to do it ...my actual requirements are that the **caller** of the module would be free to *invent* his own AST type (like sexp here), and the parsing module itself would accept any `makeTree` method from outside

Comment: ...I was hoping to be able to contrain inside the module the type of `makeTree` to be `type ASTreeMaker func(parserName string, values ...interface{}) interface{}`, but to have the user be able to pass in **any** kind of more specifically typed `makeTree` like `makeSexp(parserName string, values ...sExp) sExp` (with types like `sExp` only known to the user) and have them work by virtue of simply being more specific versions of the general `ASTreeMaker`. happen by any chance to imagine a solution for this?

Comment: my use-case is actually "backwards" from your example :) ast-tree types are not private to the module, they are *unknown* to the module, functions producing them get passed in from the outside (they are likely *private to the code that uses this module*) ...but I wanted to be able to impose some contraints *inside* the package, about these **"unknowable"** types of things produced and consumed by functions passed from outside, or at least have ...anyway, I'm **very new** to Go, like a few days, so I was expecting some painfully obvious solution I totally missed :)

Comment: or at least let the functions passed in from outside **be properly typed** even if the code that will call them will have no access to their full actual types (either with a few `void*` casts or in a dynamic language this would work in more obvious ways than my words can describe :))

Comment: @NeuronQ You're writing a book here :) I would suggest you to make a new question describing your use-case in better detail. E.g. "Here is package p1 with type T1, package p2 with type T2, and I want package p0 to use T1 and T2 in these ways, but not those ways". You get the idea.

Comment: ok, I will ...but first I'll get the untyped/interface{} version going, prefer to have a piece of working code first